# Would hybrid drive work after SSD failure

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage

Hybrid hard drive combines SSD with traditional hard drives. I know that SSD can fail much often than traditional hard drives. So I want to ask that, when the SSD part of the hybrid drive fails, would I still be able to use the traditional hard drive?

If it won't work like that, then I will consider add-in SATA cards instead, as it delegates risk much better.

EDIT:

I guess it differs from model to model, so if yes what models would work. (I am evaluating Seagate DX for now)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going with 'No' - if you loose the SSD part of your hybrid drive it will cease to function.  This is based on the fact that SSD Hybrid HDD rely on the SDD to cache data to and from the SATA connection, therefore if the SSD fails, there will be no route to the data from the SATA connection.

Comment: I would have thought that the algorithm does not blindly load the latest read file into the SSD, otherwise it would be inefficient. Which means there would still be a direct tunnel from the traditional HD to the motherboard (through the algorithm chip of course)?

Comment: I would hope so, but it may be more likely that upon failure of the SSD the firmware would report the drive as failing or failed which might make it difficult to recover data, depends on location of indexes / file allocation tables etc?

Comment: I would be concerned if the drive tries to cache to failed regions of the SSD component and then blindly reads to them. Hopefully they have SMART reporting for the SSD to stop this...